# Swap the two given indices

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an array of positive integers and two distinct valid indices, return the array with the two elements corresponding to the two indices swapped.

You may choose to use 0-indexing or 1-indexing, but the testcases below will be 0-indexed.

```
array        m n output
[1,2,3,4]    0 1 [2,1,3,4]
[5,8,9]      0 2 [9,8,5]
[11,13,15,3] 1 2 [11,15,13,3]
[11,13,15,3] 2 1 [11,15,13,3]
[11,15,15,3] 2 1 [11,15,15,3]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126201/48934), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73580/48934).

Comment: Huh, this may well be a task that many golfing languages have a hard time with but most practical languages find easy. (Lists with mutable elements aren't a common thing for golfing languages to have.) If that is the case, it'll be quite interesting. (The golfing languages will probably still win, though, because they're *so much* terser they can get away with a more complex algorithm.)

Comment: Surprised this probably isn't a dupe, but this challenge is actually creative, since it's a real challenge for many golfing languages out there.

Comment: @LeakyNun I've got downvotes (and even delete votes) like that in the past, don't worry too much about it...

Comment: Can `m` and `n` be taken as an array?

Comment: Can the output not be in the form of a list (print the integers separated by a newline instead)?

Comment: Can functions return by modifying the original array in place?

Comment: @Okx I do not understand what you mean by `m` and `n` be taken as an array.

Comment: @Neil [allowed by meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/48934)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I'm surprised that I can't find it on meta.

Comment: @ais523 I've added one more testcase.

Comment: Will the elements of the array be unique as they are in the test cases?

Comment: @Dennis nice observation. I've added one more testcase.

Comment: Full reentrancy should be a possible bonus!

Answer (score 17):

## C<del>/C++</del>, <del>53</del> <del>50</del> 39 bytes

```
f(a,m,n)int*a;{a[m]^=a[n]^=a[m]^=a[n];}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dZDLboMwEEXX@CtGSJVwMlWBNFIrmi9xqWTRpPICUwXKU3w7HcbFyaYbj@eeOw@7ePwqimW5RBpLtNLYZqezSasy/zhpZfnc7tm8tJX5hOZcNxE5YacR1li7ULpgpZhEsHZcFSszQVl1BS4xcII4o/AGNTxBbcZzRVYV55LU/V6KIPi@kvMShQ/pD4QIWpmcm2z6uw0pn4XgodrYiCdSRsWtymnElCCkCAeE5xlJ7Zx6RHhBeGWp/zOSMyFfQuzAYPgPjHfguIF1Mf6QFrfXtBIhJk5LOtR51DmUetR71BNK7tHg0SD5NbeGo0fjDc3LLw)

Saved 11 bytes thanks to @Dennis

Answer (score 10):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, <s>98</s> 95 bytes

```
f={t=_this;a=t select 0;b=+a;m=t select 1;n=t select 2;a set[m,b select n];a set[n,b select m]}
```

Modifies the array directly.

**Explanation:**

```
t=_this;                   // Give a shorter name for the array of arguments.

a=t select 0;              // Let 'a' be a pointer to the array that we modify.
                           // (The language doesn't have a concept of pointers really,
                           // yet its array variables are pointers to the actual array.)

b=+a;                      // Make a copy of the original array and save a pointer to it
                           // in the variable 'b'. This saves a few bytes later.

m=t select 1;              // Read the index arguments from the input array and save them
n=t select 2;              // to their respective variables.

a set[m,b select n];       // Do the swapping by reading the values from the copy and
a set[n,b select m]        // writing them to the original array. The last semicolon can
                           // be omitted because there are no more statements following 
                           // the last statement.
```

**Call with:**

```
array = [1,2,3,4];
str = format["%1", array];
[array, 0, 1] call f;
hint format["%1\n%2", str, array];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

Look, Ma, no temporary variable!

```
(a,m,n)=>[a[m],a[n]]=[a[n],a[m]]
```

- 4 bytes saved thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) bringing [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/48934) to my attention.

---

### Try it

Enter a comma separated list of elements for `a` and 2 integers for `m` & `n`.

```js
f=
(a,m,n)=>[a[m],a[n]]=[a[n],a[m]]
oninput=_=>o.innerText=(f(b=i.value.split`,`,+j.value,+k.value),b);o.innerText=(f(b=(i.value="5,8,9").split`,`,j.value=0,k.value=2),b)
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif}input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:100px;}#j,#k{width:50px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>a: </label><input id=i><label for=j>m: </label><input id=j type=number><label for=k>n: </label><input id=k type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: Those instructions modify the array, which means you're allowed to not return the array, which will save you a few bytes.

Comment: @Neil: You're saying to just use `(a,m,n)=>[a[m],a[n]]=[a[n],a[m]]`? That would only output the 2 swapped elements without the rest of the array (e.g., `[5,8,9],0,2` -> `[9,5]`).

Comment: @Neil: Right, which is why we need the `a` at the end to give us the complete, modified array. Or am I completely missing what you're trying to say?

Comment: @Neil: Hmm ... OK, I think I see what you'e getting at now (Sorry, trying to do too many things at the same time today). Thanks for the tip. Is there a consensus on that and, if so, would you have a link handy before I go searching for it myself?

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/48934

Comment: Surely splicing is shorter?

Comment: @Downgoat, `(a,m,n)=>a[m]=a.splice(n,1,a[m])[0]` comes in at 35 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ṛ,ḷyJ}ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlk6D3dsr/Sqfbi7@3@x0eHl@o@a1rj//x8dbaijYBSroxCtAGQoGAGxMRCbxOpwKYCkjMFSpkAhCyC2VAACsJQRVMoQqMYQqMMQpMQYLGUMNRBNKhYA)

#### How it works

```
Ṛ,ḷyJ}ị  Main link. Left argument: [i, j]. Right argument: A (array)

Ṛ        Reverse; yield [j, i].
  ḷ      Left; yield [i, j].
 ,       Pair; yield [[j, i], [i, j]].
    J}   Indices right; yield all indices of A.
   y     Transliterate; replace j with i and i with j.
      ị  Index into A.
```

Comment: tfw the wrapper is almost as long as the program...

Comment: I never knew of the existence of `y`

Comment: I knew of `y`, but didn't think of using it here. That's a pretty clever answer.

Comment: This got me thinking... is `Jelly` valid Jelly code?

Comment: @M.Herzkamp It is. I doubt its exceptionally useful though.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>41</s> 32 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to @notjagan

```python
def f(a,m,n):a[m],a[n]=a[n],a[m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI1EnVydP0yoxOjdWJzE6L9YWROiAuP8TbaMNDXUMjXUMTXWMY7lAag11jDS5Cooy80o0EjX/AwA)

Modifies its argument, which is a [valid output format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/64121).

Comment: It's funny how it's not even golfed that much comparing to idiomatic python code.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
yyP)w(
```

Indices are 1-based.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v7IyQLNc4///aENDBUNjBUNTBeNYrmgjIAkA)

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `[11 13 15 3]`, `[2 3]`.

```
yy   % Take two inputs implicitly. Duplicate them
     % STACK: [11 13 15 3], [2 3], [11 13 15 3], [2 3]
P    % Flip
     % STACK: [11 13 15 3], [2 3], [11 13 15 3], [3 2]
)    % Reference indexing (pick indexed entries)
     % STACK: [11 13 15 3], [2 3], [15 13]
w    % Swap
     % STACK: [11 13 15 3], [15 13], [2 3]
(    % Assignment indexing (write values into indexed entries). Implicitly display
     % STACK: [11 15 13 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
{e\}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fU133vzo1pvZ/XUGOn25txv9oQwUjBWMFk1gFEDBQMOSKNlWwULCE8EEiRlzRhoYKhsYKhqYKxkBhQwwRIwVDAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>48 43</strike> 31 bytes

```cs
(a,m,n)=>a[m]+=a[n]-(a[n]=a[m])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LCsIwELz3KxZPCcZCEU81gngTBcGDh9JDiFEW7EaSqIj022tSwQc4sMOys7MP7UfaOtNBhD4p72Hj7NGpJkuVR88JPqiAGq4W97BWSIy/pU9Twvbug2nyuQ5oaYoUqlpETjGDg8w6pkQjiMuZqpp6KFVF9YgllqnAuzL7mXdVDpDOlwASyNyqGh5QFAKKcYyJgDG05Y/hwPr2qEaRl/@OW1jy9mTyncNgVkiG@eCQjvnSxs8GYiBeK/mXve2ztnsC)

Swaps the numbers in the original array, no temporary variables used. Nonetheless I can't take credit for this answer as it has been [Neil's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127839/swap-the-two-given-indices#comment315239_127842).

Comment: @LeakyNun it does not seem to work, as that leaves a[m] with a value of 0. [Try it yourself!](https://tio.run/##bU9NC4JAEL37KwZPCpsg0skMolsUBB06iMGybTKgs7G7GSH@dluNPoQezGOYN28@hJkJpWUPDqLixsBeq1Lz2hsq7cgDjOUWBTQKz7DjSEH4kb5NAw4PY2UdrYRFRQskmxfM8RBLuGReH3BWMwqzJc/r4pTxnEZ@533qTeY1XAPS9WYhA5L3vIAW4phBnLiYM0igSyeGSzC2O9WJYfrvuLUioyoZHTVauUWSgbEaqYw2yn3mM5@9VoY/9m7Muv4J)

Comment: `(a,m,n)=>a[m]+=a[n]-(a[n]=a[m])` seems to work though.

Comment: (These answers are all also valid in ES6 JavaScript, no?)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>17</strike> 16 bytes

```
hV(A=UgV UgW¹hWA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/PyNMw9E2ND1MITQ9/NDOjHDH//@jDXWMdIx1TGIVDBQMAQ)

Saved a byte thanks to ETHproductions

Comment: Nice. Don't think you need the comma though.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks, you're right.

Comment: [Alternative 16 byte implementation](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=WD1VWGhWVWdXIFhoV1VnVg==&input=WzEsMiwzLDRdCjAKMQ==) but I'm still convinced there's a shorter solution.

Comment: [15 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QT1VZ1Y7aFZVZ1e5aFdB&input=WzEgMiAzXSAxIDI=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 42 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@coredump](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/903/coredump).*

```lisp
(lambda(a i j)(rotatef(elt a i)(elt a j)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU1LCsIwEN3nFI@KMLMQqtbfccY2gZaJlXRU3PTqsUILbty9/6u1He6ZGh@ekhDfm@ElE1eJ10ZI0KJjSr2J@UBeDZPEM@iYObNzP21JCSsqscUOe1Q44IgTzrgwOwp9imIwFKOM62LOf43HrRbV5X4ZKlH9b@UP)

Quite straight forward, since there is a Common Lisp macro to swap: `rotatef`.

Comment: You could use ELT instead of AREF

Comment: @coredump Right, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
(a,m,n)=>(x=a[m],a[m]=a[n],a[n]=x)
```

- *-2 Bytes because the function is altering the array. No need to return the array. Thanks to @Neil*

### Demo

```js
f=

(a,m,n)=>(x=a[m],a[m]=a[n],a[n]=x)

let a1=[1,2,3,4], a2=[5,8,9], a3=[11,13,15,3]

f(a1,0,1);
f(a2,0,2);
f(a3,1,2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(a1)); //[2,1,3,4]
console.log(JSON.stringify(a2)); //[9,8,5]
console.log(JSON.stringify(a3)); //[11,15,13,3]
```

Comment: Those instructions modify the array, which means you're allowed to not return the array, which will save you a few bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Shenzhen I/O, 735 Bytes

23¥, 810 Power, 48 Lines of Code

```
[traces] 
......................
......................
......................
......................
......................
......................
.14.14.14.............
.94.14.14.............
.A........1C..........
.3554..95556..........
.9554.16..............
.A....................
.2....................
......................

[chip] 
[type] UC6
[x] 4
[y] 2
[code] 
  slx x0
  mov x1 acc
  mov x1 dat
  mov acc x3
  mov dat x3
  mov acc x3
  mov dat x3

[chip] 
[type] UC6
[x] 8
[y] 5
[code] 
  slx x2
  mov x2 x1
  mov x0 dat
  mov x2 x1
  mov x0 acc
  mov x2 x1
  mov dat 

[chip] 
[type] UC4X
[x] 2
[y] 6
[code] 
  slx x0
  mov 0 x3
j:  mov x0 acc
  mov acc x2
  teq acc 0
- jmp j
  mov -999 x1

[chip] 
[type] RAM
[x] 5
[y] 6
```

[image: SIO]

DISCLAIMER: Arrays are 0-terminated in this. Arrays are a pain in the ass to work with in Shenzhen I/O otherwise.

I actually made a steam level for this game. You can play it [here.](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=954747779)

EDIT: Aaand I just realized I said that the array in was ordered. Heck.

Comment: Welcome to the site This is really cool! do you think that you might be able to remove some of the whitespace in the file and still have Shenzhen IO accept the file?  I don't know how much you have fiddled with it, but you should try and see how flexible the format is.

Comment: I haven't played around with it! On the other hand, I am axing the header for the puzzle which contains the puzzle name and solution name, so I dunno if I should bother.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

```
iʰ{pᵗz=ᵗ!|}htI&h∋↙I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/5mnNlQXPNw6vcoWSCjW1GaUeKplPOroftQ20/P//2iF6GhDHSMdYx2TWB2FaAMdw1gQHW2qY6FjCRExgogYGuoYGusYmuoYg7iG2IWNYPpBwqaowgqxAA)

The process of writing this [generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) was fairly clumsy, so there's probably some further golfing to do. I may not have thought to use `i` if I hadn't initially thought I had some use for the value half of the pair it outputs! Takes input as `[array, [m, n]]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/), 48 bytes

```java
(a,b,c)->{int t=a[b];a[b]=a[c];a[c]=t;return a;}
```

Input:

```java
int[] a
int b
int c
```

Comment: How do you do lambdas with three arguments in Java?

Comment: @LeakyNun I made a custom class for it.

Comment: The same logic (and byte count) can be achieved with currying and no custom classes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVDBaoQwEL37FXNUiKG6LbRYA70Ueuhpj@IhulFiNUoybhHx221kdffgHpfOIXm8Gea9NxU/c7/thKpOP7NsulYjVJajPcqafmjNBxM5u0bRqxxlq@jnCiLH6fqsljnkNTcGvrlUMDpga@UNcrTfuZUnaGzXPaKWqkxS4Lo03jq81Lbz/UuhKIVOUrLj7jHXccYYFBDP3GeZz3KfjVIhYMyTLI2Wx6J8QXkaY6QF9loBj6Z5cxBdvRwHg6KhbY@0s3axVu7lKBTbSwC3oLzr6sFV4vdmAUYICIQEDgSeYfLWmacNBJ7nPUTlhcArgbc7EuGjJAKbJLA5Aqt1uAkF/yUU7o82OdP8Bw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: Those instructions modify the array, which means you're allowed to not return the array, which will save you a few bytes.

Comment: @Okx could you show your code for the custom class?

Comment: @LeakyNun I'm not _Okx_, but here is a [Try it now example](https://tio.run/##LU/LjsMgDLznK3wEiaLt44ay0n7A9tJjlYNDSUU2gQicrqoo355C6cVjj0fjcY8P3PnJuP72t9lx8oGgT5ycyQ7yJwR8RlVVesAY4RetWyoA68iEDrWBcx7fxLWBjhVEkQloC2iukmatUomEZDWcwUENG0PRCs1330uWUY3XtlG5pE7nTjc1qWBoDg5QrZvKHtPcDsnjY/Xw9gZjisUuFKy75@u8ZLo8I5lR@pnklFY0OFbekeSLmDnZMWf@S/xlLw7iKE6rgC8Be84/udftBQ) with _Okx_'s current answer and custom interface.

Comment: And @Neil is right, you can get rid of the return: [`(a,b,c)->{int t=a[b];a[b]=a[c];a[c]=t;}`](https://tio.run/##LVBBbsMgELz7FXsEiaCm7Q25Uh7QXHKMfFgTXOHaYME6VWT57S4YX3aX0czOsD0@8eQn4/rH72bHyQeCPmFyJjvISwj4iqqq9IAxwjdat1QA1pEJHWoD1/wEeHr7gI4l/N4AikyAtjTNVaKsVSqRkKyGKzioYWMoWqH56WvJNKrx3jYqlzTpPOmmJrVuKkunuR2S9Niw240pDLtRsO4nm/KS5IiQcycTZ/4KspzFu/gQn6vaWU52bOcIeBNw5gW9vSKZUfqZ5JTW0uBYOYAkX4yKiB9fWrd/)

Comment: And based on [_Carlos Alejo_'s amazing C# answer (with @Neil's help)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127842/52210), you can make it even shorter by getting rid of the temporary variable: [`(a,b,c)->a[b]+=a[c]-(a[c]=a[b])`](https://tio.run/##LY/BboMwEETvfMUebdVYSdsbolI/oLnkiDgsjqlMwUb2kiiK@HZqYy5r@WlmZ3bAO5Zu1na4/W1mmp0nGCKTC5lRfnuPz1AVhRoxBPhBY18FgLGkfY9KwyV9Ae7O3KBnkTctoEgC6PKjeBUlaxFHICSj4AIWatgYik4oXn5h07VvNTaqLVmadQJ8q5JlXroxWg7nHjPFEuxK3tjfFMZzgyM69Y3LrX5k8jqLd/EhPtdqV1nZs10j4CTgzDO9PgPpSbqF5BzX0mhZPlySy0HZxI9T1u0f) (**31 bytes**)

Comment: _cough cough_ `Collections::swap` is [17 bytes](https://gist.github.com/SocraticPhoenix/0d75145733f91018d7c9740fda3e42e7)... at least assuming [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10098/56085) holds for this challenge...

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix yep, but... the full name is `java.util.Collections::swap`, so 27 bytes, not 17. Go ahead, post it :)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire still shorter :)

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix Yeah, of course, that's why I said to post it! You'll get at least one +1, mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
D²è³ǝ¹³è²ǝ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5dCmwysObT4@99DOQ5uBrE3H5/7/H22oY6RjrGMSy2XAZQgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
@(a,n){a(n)=a(flip(n)),a}{2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnT7M6USNP0zZRIy0nswDI0tRJrK02qv2fphFtqGOkY6xjEqsDYsVqcgGFTHUsdCzBAsYQAUNDHUNjHUNTIF8n2girqDFI838A)

Quite satisfied with this one actually :)

Takes input on the form: `f([1,2,3,4],[1,2])`, 1-indexed.

**Explanation:**

```matlab
@(a,n)                         % Anonymous function that takes two 1-dimensional
                               % arrays as input
      {               , }      % Create a cell with two elements
       a(n)=a(flip(n))         % One element are the two number at indices given by
                               % the second input array. This will be a 1x2 array
      {a(n)=a(flip(n)),a}      % Place those two in a cell together with the entire array a
                               % a is now updated, thanks to Octave's inline assignment
      {a(n)=a(flip(n)),a}{2}   % Return the second element
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 7 bytes

```
p
ZRi
i
```

Takes a list and a pair of indices.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P@/gCsqKJMr8///aDMFUwVzBctYrmhDBeNYAA)

### Explanation

Jellyfish happens to have a "modify items at indices" function, `Z`, which does exactly what we need.
The two `i`s grab the inputs from STDIN.
`Z` takes as arguments the second input, the reversal function `R`, and the list.
Then `Z` performs the modification, and `p` prints the result.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 38 bytes

```
function(x,a,b){x[c(a,b)]=x[c(b,a)];x}
```

Feels rather long, but I can't get it much shorter. Sadly it requires the explicit returning through `x`, requiring `{}` around the function body. `pryr::f()` doesn't recognise the need for `x` as function argument so doesn't work :/.

Comment: I think `function(x,i)replace(x,i,rev(i))` would work, even with pryr syntax.

Comment: @Giuseppe Ah, I was looking for a convenient function to do the swap, but was searching with the wrong terms. Feel free to post that as an own answer.

Comment: @Giuseppe I think you need to do `replace(x,i,x[rev(i)])`, else you'll place the indices instead of their values.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 + [InverseY](https://github.com/PlutoPowered/InverseY/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gmail/socraticphoenix/inversey/many/Consumer3.java), 27 bytes

```
java.util.Collections::swap
```

Just calls the swap function... this is a method reference of the type `Consumer3<List, Integer, Integer>`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDBTsMwDL3vK3zs0Ig2ygE2NmnaCQmkSvsCk2VVSppEsTs0oX17cQIMoiS23rPfi9PhCW9DNL47vI@2jyExdIKpga1TN6tJHN6c1aAdEsErWg@fk1@QGFnCKdgD9EJVe07Wt0opwNTSVEpB1i54GnqT6qcXSzyDZ8@mNemabIA@MMIaxj/nXXDOaLbSulxmelwVrawALl9r2KaEZ1JIGazmM7iTs5D9KKmEh@l3T25XGp2rXPG/F/qH2p@JTa/CwCrK09n5UiPs5TqlwCYdUZt/gzRi04hHU2/yf2Sp8gvFpVlALDzEUgKxFsGseBm/AA) (header and footer for boilerplate & copy of `Consumer3` interface)

Comment: You don't need to add " + InverseY". It's valid in vanilla Java 8.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
(a=#;a[[{##2}]]=a[[{#3,#2}]];a)&
```

Comment: `a[[{##2}]]==a[[{#3,#2}]]` should be `a[[{##2}]]=a[[{#3,#2}]]` (using `Set`, not `Equals`)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>111</s> 65 bytes (0-indexed)

Swift is already notorious for being one of the worst code-golf languages, but here is a function <s>that makes use of ternary expressions</s>:

```swift
func t(l:[Int],m:Int,n:Int){var r=l;r[m]=l[n];r[n]=l[m];print(r)}
```

[Check it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/594bac0de7b3821b65a0c480)
- **Usage:** `t(l:[1,2,3],m:0,n:1)`.

Comment: Using a default param for r would save you bytes and you can also just mutate the passed array (AFAIK swift array are pass by value)

Comment: Default parameter in Swift? How can I do that?

Comment: And parameters are constants in Swift @Downgoat

Answer (score 1):

## [k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)) ([kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona)), 13 bytes

```
{x[y]:x@|y;x}
```

Pretty basic, but it works. Ex:

```
k){x[y]:x@|y;x}[1 2 3 4; 0 1]
2 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings)!*

30 bytes of code + `-pa` flags.

```perl
@F[pop@p,@p]=@F[@p=<>];$_="@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAsS/zu4RRfkFzgU6DgUxNoCOQ4FtjZ2sdYq8bZKDm5K//8bKhgpGCuYKJgqmCmYK1goWCoYGnAZcVkAAA)

Quite straight forward, using array slices.

Comment: Hey hey, tinkered with this a little and managed to save 3 bytes! `@F[pop@p,@p]=@F[@p=<>];$_="@F"`.

Comment: @DomHastings Hmm, nice, as always! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 42 bytes

Modify the array in place with a temp value.

```
f(r,m,n){int*a=r;r=a[m];a[m]=a[n];a[n]=r;}
```

## C, <s>60</s> 58 bytes

A little more interesting, not using any temp value...

```
f(a,m,n)int*a;{a[m]+=a[n];a[n]-=a[m];a[n]*=-1;a[m]-=a[n];}
```

## C, 49 bytes

Using XOR

```
f(a,m,n)int*a;{a[m]^=a[n];a[n]^=a[m];a[m]^=a[n];}
```

Comment: Heh, I was just about to post `f(x,i,j,t)int*x;{t=x[i];x[i]=x[j];x[j]=t;}`.

Comment: @Dennis you saved me two bytes on the other solution, thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the second solution be shorter (and safer) with `^`?

Comment: -1 for the XOR version using a define instead of a function `#define X(x,y,z)x[y]^=x[z],x[z]^=x[y],x[y]^=x[z]`

Comment: `f(r,m,n){int*a=r;r=a[m];a[m]=a[n];a[n]=r;}` is broken: SIGSEGV.

Comment: @BodoThiesen compile it for 32bits with -m32 
[Try it online!][TIO-j48vts9v]

[C (gcc)]: https://gcc.gnu.org/
[TIO-j48vts9v]: https://tio.run/##JYzNCsMgEITvPkUQWrTZQP5uNk8iHhZbU6GaYNJTyGP3WmvMHGZnPpjV1ah1jIYFcOD5Zv16wyGIMKB0ShyWkj@SV4nv0QqH1jNONlIkpUGBUg25nOhQAy100Oe@i3yyGXZFWSuooeGCnGgKTNh7L@aQnhlGLw@ggNKWpeL83M6fdWGUpraT@NPmjeMSK9e1Xz9VGvXr@Qc "C (gcc) – Try It Online"

Comment: -m32 only works if there is a 32 bit mode available. So, you should at least clarify, that your solution is a x86_32 only solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>17</s> 8 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to Leaky Num.

```
@LQ.rUQE
```

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40LQ.rUQE&input=%5B11%2C13%2C15%2C3%5D%0A%281%2C2%29&debug=0)

This is 0-indexed, and the indices are provided as a tuple: `(n, m)`.

**Explanations**

```
@LQ.rUQE

     UQ     # Generate [0, 1, 2, ..., len(input)]
       E    # Get the indices as the tuple (1, 2)
   .r       # Translate each element of UQ to its cyclic successor in E
            # Now the indices are permuted (e.g. [0, 2, 1, ..., len(input)]
@LQ         # For each index, get it's value. Implicit print
```

Comment: 8 bytes: [`@LQ.rUQE`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40LQ.rUQE&input=%5B11%2C13%2C15%2C3%5D%0A%281%2C2%29&debug=0)

Comment: @LeakyNun It's so different I think you can post it for yourself!

Comment: I'm the OP; I don't post on my own challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

```julia
x*t=x[t]=x[t[[2,1]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5BCgIxDAXQdXuKLlP5m7QWdOFJShaCCpWhylCht68ZBmEYMIsPyYNPnp@pXNMY/dAuPTdZIucAFpHxeM2OOpp3pVpDlBkBEUeB09HNBfGwxlFOOOG83leJP2EGR3BCVNbmfxI3bYuknXhrjdE3Nd9zqW2q1L2919v4Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
#~Permute~Cycles@#2&
```

Pure function taking two arguments in the following 1-indexed (and possibly abusive) format: the second test case `[5,8,9]; 0 2; [9,8,5]` would be called as

```
#~Permute~Cycles@#2& [ {5,8,9} , {{1,3}} ]
```

(spaces are extraneous and just for visible parsing). `Permute` is the builtin function that applies a permutation to a list, and `Cycles[{{a,b}}]` represents the permutation that exchanges the `a`th and `b`th elements of a list and ignores the rest.

Comment: What do the `~` do?

Comment: `~` is Mathematica's infix notation for a binary function: `x~f~y` means the same thing as `f[x,y]`.

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Machine Code, 10 bytes

```
8B 04 8B 87 04 93 89 04 8B C3
```

This is a function written in 32-bit x86 machine code that swaps the values at the specified indices in a given array. The array is [modified in-place](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/4942#4942), and the function does not return a value.

A custom calling convention is used, requiring the function's parameters to be [passed in registers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8508/58518):

- The address of the array (pointer to its first element) is passed in the `EBX` register.
- The zero-based index of element A is passed in the `ECX` register.
  <sub>(Assumed to be a valid index.)</sub>
- The zero-based index of element B is passed in the `EDX` register.
  <sub>(Assumed to be a valid index.)</sub>

This keeps the size down and complies with all formal requirements, but does mean that the function cannot be easily called from other languages like C. You'd need to call it from another assembly-language program. (You could rewrite it to use *any* input registers, though, without affecting the byte count; there's nothing magical about the ones I chose.)

Ungolfed:

```
8B 04 8B     mov  eax, DWORD PTR [ebx+ecx*4]   ; get value of element A
87 04 93     xchg eax, DWORD PTR [ebx+edx*4]   ; swap element A and element B
89 04 8B     mov  DWORD PTR [ebx+ecx*4], eax   ; store new value for element A
C3           ret                               ; return, with array modified in-place
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 34 bytes

```
pryr::f(`[<-`(a,c(m,n),a[c(n,m)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES2015), <strike>66</strike> <strike>57</strike> 49 bytes

A different (alas, longer) approach than previous JavaScript answers

```
(s,h,o,w=s.splice.bind(s))=>w(h,1,...w(o,1,s[h]))
```

Source

```
const swap = (arr, a, b, splice) => {
  splice(a, 1, ...splice(arr[b], 1, arr[a]))
}
```

Comment: `(s,h,o,w=s.splice.bind(s))=>w(h,1,...w(o,1,s[h]))` 49 bytes

Comment: Forgot about them default args. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### awk, 31 bytes

```
{c=$a;$a=$b;$b=c;a=$1;b=$2}NR>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/OtlWJdFaJdFWJclaJck22RrIMrROslUxqvULsjP8/99QwYgLiBWMFUwA)

Takes input in the format

```
1 2
1 2 3 4
```

and outputs as

```
2 1 3 4
```

(1-indexed).

#### Explanation

The entire program is a missing pattern with an action followed by a pattern with a missing action.

Since a missing pattern runs on each line, the code inside the braces runs for both input lines. The `c=$a;$a=$b;$b=c;` part swaps the two values at indices `a` and `b` (through the temporary variable `c`). This only has an effect on the second line, since on the first line `a` and `b` are not yet defined. The `a=$1;b=$2` part defines `a` to be the first field and `b` to be the second field, which sets the appropriate values for the first part to run on the second line.

Since a missing action is equivalent to `{print}`, the pattern prints every line it matches. This pattern in particular is `NR>1`: that is, print whenever the line number is greater than 1, which happens to be line 2. This runs after the swapping of values has taken place, thus completing the task.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 bytes

```
£gY¶V?W:Y¶W?V:Y
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=o2dZtlY/VzpZtlc/VjpZ&input=WzExLDEzLDE1LDNdCjIKMQ==)

---

### Explanation

```
       :Implicit input of array U and integers V & W
£      :Map over the array (with Y being the index of the current element), replacing each element with...
g      :  The element in the array at index...
Y¶V?W  :    W, if Y equals V
:Y¶W?V :    or V, if Y equals W
:Y     :    or just Y otherwise
       :Implicit output of modified array
```

Comment: Nice technique, looks a little verbose though... but I can't find a way to golf it.

Comment: @ETHproductions: yeah, I'm *still* convinced there's a shorter way, just haven't had the time to come back and find it and it looks like I won't until tomorrow :(

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 17 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{@[x;(|)y;:;x y]}
```

**Example:**

```
q){@[x;(|)y;:;x y]}[1 2 3 4;0 1]
2 1 3 4
```

**Explanation:**

A q version of the k answer by Simon. Apply the assign `:` function to x at indices reverse-y with value of x indexed at y. Broken down you can see more clearly:

```
q)x:1 2 3 4
q)y:0 1
q)x y
1 2
q)(|)y
1 0
q)x(|)y
2 1
q)@[x;(|)y;:;x y]
2 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, <strike>64</strike> 49 bytes

<strike>$f=$args;$t=$f[0];($t[$f[1]],$t[$f[2]]=$t[$f[2]],$t[$f[1]])>$;$t</strike>

```
param($a,$b,$c)($a[$b],$a[$c]=$a[$c],$a[$b])>$;$a
```

At least somewhat better solution.

Also I have no idea why redirecting to $ even works ^^

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 10 bytes

```
ÀGYÀGVpVp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3CDeyQQhxXwhxX8/29oyGVozGVoymX83/C/EQA)

This takes input with each number to a line, and indices as program arguments. 1-indexed.

Answer (score -1):

## C, 42 bytes (one extra argument on function call)

```
f(a,m,n,t)int*a;{t=a[m];a[m]=a[n];a[n]=t;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jVNdb5swFH33r7hrNAmYu8QkSMsYk7aVdXlpp0brC6WSxUeDFkxEaKcsys/uc3ptA2UpmYp08b3HPudcYxyd3kXRfp8anOZU0MrMRGVxd1t5PMhDV74wEzIToVe5u/3QIr8uzvzvswv/DL76P75czy6vPkKt0PAl8VYxb73n3N2Rg3U4wFEv8vq2yHx2PvfPr2UjpTLYKopXumUvp0SONSQEt/NQZDHSZCsWcAoyyfUgTNgSqB/VK3ig5Fr0WbcDqaaIdhhkIlrexwl84ut1UlbvF5872LqKs@IQKjNxJzEiLTkLGAvRdwsjCozChIIcwMYYY0zqnDU17FzNtAOYtkxcImcdjA8YU6qbnda1o6qGOW49mWKiB8OMoQJztI@qHY3BuGVOWqbddPtKpnOE6fQwnYZJBnGSZiKBn1eX3/z53OBlyTcmxAXq3LRHssJPWqXGydv1jTihMNCr3M4KfTjGOvubFGmjMoS6tmrA89D2HdjyT5FIYIf/qMiNRMVqEzSzYXc2T/JotTHkAqr5qIXbOjA5op12icEobDIW9m3kjTTLV4dmGI34/3yV4g7@LLJlAsbI1L9izjNhyOvSvRbth2em@xK0@8BxHzjpAx0EXxwiXy6h@I0H2Z0sk@q@FDDCa@eS/aMoTiMeLZIn)

## C, 44 bytes

```
f(a,m,n)int*a;{int t=a[m];a[m]=a[n];a[n]=t;}
```