# Convert Numbers to Letters, and vice-versa in a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Based on a list of numbers and their equivalent letters, take a string input, replace the characters of that string with the equivalent number/letter and output the result.

#### List

> - 1 = a
> - 2 = b
> - 3 = c
> - 4 = d
> - 5 = e
> - 6 = f
> - 7 = g
> - 8 = h
> - 9 = i
> - 0 = j

#### Input

> thisisastring1124

#### Output

> t89s9s1str9n7aabd

#### Rules

- Numbers are equivalent to lowercase letters only.
- Any character outside the list will be left as is.
- Input string must not contain spaces.
- Either full program or function is permitted.
- Since it's code-golf, fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Nice challenge!

Comment: May we swap uppercase letters instead?

Comment: Only lowercase letters, uppercase letters would be outside the scope of the list.

Comment: Will the input contain only letters and numbers, or might other non-space characters (eg. punctuation) be in it?

Comment: Input string can contain any other character except spaces, but anything outside the list will be left untouched in the output string.

Answer (score 14):

### bash, 18 bytes

```bash
tr 1-90a-j a-j1-90
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwVDX0iBRN0sBiEFMoFhGZnFmcWJxSVFmXrqhoZEJAA)

Comment: How does this take input/give output? stdin and stdout?

Comment: @NicHartley Yes.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>76</s> 68 bytes

```python
lambda w:w.translate(dict(zip(s,s[::-1])))
s=b'1234567890jihgfedcba'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLDoIwEADQvadw12mixgJ@aMJJ1MWUUjoES8NMQvTy1bd8@SNxSXUJ3bPM@HYe95vdTrJi4hllAE@9wJcy8IEf1h7NS2u9484pU9XN5Xq7t@eJ4hgG3ztUJa@UBAIoicTEyPKP0ZiqUVqXHw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>45</s> 23 bytes

```perl6
tr/1..90a..j/a..j1..90/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@kSN9QT8/SIFFPL0sfRIB5@kCJjMzizOLE4pKizLx0Q0Mjk3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Just a plain transliteration regex.

Comment: Using TR would be shorter here, also you don't have to separate all those parts of the sequence: `TR/1..90a..j/a..j1..90/`   https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzokSN9QT8/SIFFPL0sfRIB5@rX/ixMrFdI0lEoyMoszixOLS4oy89INDY1MlDSt/wMA

Comment: @PhilH Ha, I was literally just searching that operator up! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 17 bytes

```perl
y;a-j1-90;1-90a-j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/SOlE3y1DX0sAaRADZ//@XZGQWZxYnFpcUZealGxoamfzLLyjJzM8r/q9bAAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 9 bytes

```
žmÁAT£JÂ‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L7cw42OIYcWex1uetSw8P//kozM4szixOKSosy8dENDIxMA)

**Explanation**

```
žmÁ         # push 0987654321
   AT£      # push abcdefghij
      J     # join strings
       Â    # bifurcate
        ‡   # transliterate
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 12 bytes

```
T`a-j09-1`Ro
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JCFRN8vAUtcwISj///@SjMzizOLE4pKizLx0Q0MjEwA) Explanation:

```
T``
```

Perform a transliteration.

```
a-j09-1
```

The source list is the letters `a-j`, then `0`, then the digits `9-1`.

```
Ro
```

The destination list is the source list reversed, i.e. the digits `1-9`, then `0`, then the letters `j-a`.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 38 bytes

```
rplc[:(;~"0|.)'9876543210jabcdefghi'"1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoIwEAXQfU/x081IQpoWEKGGk7iCytASo4RhiV69vrdmlsHAwsPmfXuFh7/cf9qepqC@u7XXpq6cXccpPGdeYiLtcqG0AfFgCCW@HixKzSF@wKAjJkkyyrGn9@Jc1ZDKfw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>82</s> 78 bytes

```python
lambda i,l='1234567890jihgfedcba':''.join((x,l[~l.find(x)])[x in l]for x in i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcy9DoMgFEDhV7lhARJiqrV/Jj6JdQApcg0FIwx06atT7fad5ayfZINviumfxcm30hJQuJ7Wzbm9XG/3x2lBO5uXnpSkHaXVEtAzloUbvq4y6DXLfORDBvTgRhM2@BN5ORwOMyLVtA@JAJIsRowypg39XNdNS3gH6x4JDAu8/AA)

-4 with thanks to @ovs

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(e=/[1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j]/g,c=>e[e.search(c)^1],e+=e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDsIgEADQu3QFsVKp1eqCXqSpyTgdPg2BhiFeH9874AeMJZz1mvJOzZrGZmFV6IyAJMgMq4bxe8dpf9DTzu7l3@F2bIPr0Sy0kmKCgl6g/Oitp4sh2TAnzpFUzE5Y0VUfODBwLSE5rcepk7L9AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
function(s)chartr("0-9ja-i","ja-i0-9",s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYgxCsAgDAD3PiOLBhS0dOnQx0jBGgcLSXx/aofjuGOrl9U5bqV3eMG7FVb2kOLZSyQI8GsVBEGr3mkjISmiTOPJeT8cbmv3KZoWDu0D)

Surprisingly, R is decent at this kind of [string](/questions/tagged/string) challenge, because it has a `tr`-like function as in the [Bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167851/67312). No idea why it exists, but I'm grateful for it!

Comment: Amazing! Didn't know chartr() understood regex.

Comment: @snoram not quite regex; it specifies [in the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html) that "Ranges are supported in the specifications, but character classes and repeated characters are not."

Answer (score 3):

## MS-SQL, 71 bytes

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(v,'1234567890abcdefghij','abcdefghij1234567890')FROM t
```

The new SQL 2017 function [`TRANSLATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) performs individual character replacement, so is ideally suited for this purpose. See [my similar answer in a prior challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163167/70172).

Input is via a pre-existing table **t** with varchar column **v**, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341). To replace only lowercase letters, the table must be created using a *case-sensitive collation*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(v varchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>80</s> 66 bytes

```hs
map(!"1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j")
e!(a:b:y)|e==a=b|e==b=a|1<2=e!y
e!_=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcy9DsIgFEDh3acA4tAOTQTrX@N9ClcTc8FbQGlDCg5N@uxinc7wJcdhelMIxcK9DBgrLiQqvTft80DH/mTP7uJ3L1FviFfY6W6uFwJA0P9owEVeFRCfV38ArQs/MmDxk295YltmmcjOJ58w5cmPVkrVivI1fUCbSmNi/AE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
⁵Øaḣ,ØDṙ1¤ċÞ⁸Ṛy)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//4oG1w5hh4bijLMOYROG5mTHCpMSLw57igbjhuZp5Kf///3RoaXNpc2FzdHJpbmcxMTI0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 13 bytes

```
Xz+jk+0_S9<GT
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Xz%2Bjk%2B0_S9%3CGT&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=thisisastring1124&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
Xz+jk+0_S9<GT – Full program.
       _S9    – Yield [9, 8, 7, ..., 1]
     +0       – Prepend a 0.
   jk         – Join to a single string.
  +       <GT – And append the first 10 letters of the alphabet to it.
                Yields 0987654321abcdefghij.
Xz            – Transliterates the input from the above to the above reversed.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>81</strike> 72 bytes

Thanks to Giacomo Garabello for the suggestions.

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s++=*s-97U<11?(*s-6)%10+48:*s-48U<11?(*s-9)%10+97:*s;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzRCoIwGEbvfYpBBNvMaCGpzewpuoouxkr9oWbsn96Iz76mQdDdOeeDTyeN1n4FRj/7@4OU6O7QbdvK11S3ynJkY91ZKjnG8YljUmSXUogzDXhga7GL0/wYOM1/uVhykYUsmZw8GEdeCgydQdlGb@ZjwnnggZExIgRqOg@V@Cohiw9XcWNy8Xfv8C9N0eS9awEBFToLphFin34A)

Comment: You can remove 6 chars by altering the input string instead of print it out `putchar(...)`-->`*s=...` and other 4 by replacing `*s-48U<11` with `*s<59` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY3NTsMwEITP5CmsVpUcp0F1SZsGp/AUnICD6/x4UetUXpceqrw6xglIOXBgT6OZb3ZU2irl52DU8VLVpERXQXevn3xDlZaWYXxrOksFQ4FJEjPcM0yL/KXk/JkGuY0XfJVku0eG5aYYrWK0ijxYovdgHDlJMHQQ0rZqOfwljAX9GZNbRMKFCTICsOcCygETEOZ@4xGhQ@EV3mMR3Z1tgBs6WyBJyWxJpugf/M38ofuo995pQECJLpAt5@vM8/VDttnmu2IlD6qqm1bDh5/kFHtpOqdr62p0P/0rOJ2Zy@lQWwzcl2qOskWfXr8B "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello `*s<59` breaks if characters like `$` are in the input, which is why I did `*s-48U` ([0..47] becomes [-48..-1], which becomes a large unsigned value.) As the question didn't specify whether non-alnums were valid, I went with the more conservative interpretation.

Comment: Fair enough. The OP commented recently that every other character is valid but not the space. But you can still use my first suggestion

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYyxDoIwFEV3vuItJm2RhGdQwKJ8BZNxaJoAJRFNX2Uh@Ou14OR2zrnJ1Umntfct072ygvjcPi2TguL4Iigp86ZCrFnAE99hGmfFOXDRVEesyzz5CAo1JMnl4s3o4KHMyFZQttP79RSECDxxmCMA07J1uOJPATafbnjncvPX29FfWqLFe9cbMqTIWTN2iIcsHb4 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 57 bytes

```
#=1234567890
a='abcdefghij'
say translate(arg(1),a #,# a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 94 bytes

```
-join($args|% t*y|%{if(1+($p=($s='1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j').IndexOf($_))){$s[$p-bxor1]}else{$_}})
```

Test script:

```
$f = {
-join($args|% t*y|%{if(1+($p=($s='1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j').IndexOf($_))){$s[$p-bxor1]}else{$_}})
}

&$f "thisisastring1124"
```

### Explanation

- `$args` - argument strings
- `$args|% t*y` - expands to `|ForEach-Object -Method ToCharArray` equivalent of `"$args".ToCharArray()`
- `($s='1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j').IndexOf($_)` - find a char in the string, returns a position or -1 if not found. Let $s stores the string which contains a paired char on neighbor positions that differ by the last bit: 0+1, 2+3, 4+5....
- `if(1+($p=...))` - if position was found
- `$p-bxor1` - position bit xor 1

Comment: Nice trick with the `-bxor1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 107 bytes

```r
function(s){a=utf8ToInt(s);l=a>96&a<107;n=a>47&a<58;a[n]=(a[n]-9)%%10+97;a[l]=(a[l]+4)%%10+48;intToUtf8(a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxC8IwEIbh3f9Rm1CERKJNiXF3r5N0OIRoSrhCc5nE3x5PHe6D9xlurcHXUPBOcUGR5Qt8oWDH5YLE6ZKH83Dcwkmr3iGH6TkO1sENJy@@uxtk02jVDT1j@mGaOvNHY11EGpcrPxUg3zWIlp4xxwyZ1ogPrfemlRvmuWRSfK2sHw)

First attempt, definitely improvable...

Comment: `chartr` is your friend here, I think.

Comment: https://tio.run/##FYgxCsAgDAD3PiOLBhS0dOnQx0jBGgcLSXx/aofjuGOrl9U5bqV3eMG7FVb2kOLZSyQI8GsVBEGr3mkjISmiTOPJeT8cbmv3KZoWDu0D like that

Comment: @Giuseppe : awesome! I didn't know of chartr function. Please post it as your answer, the approach is totally different ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 96 bytes

```rust
|x|x.bytes().map(|x|match
x{49..=57=>x+48,97..=105=>x-48,48=>106,106=>48,x=>x}as
char).collect()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BboMwEEX3nGLKorJVYuGKFNzIXKIHqCbUFCJwE89UcpXk7HSUL/3Fe6uXfom3McKKc1QargXIlsAwvsMY1TNx0rDr4YPTHL/Bb7d8y@b4x4GUNiuelYgVeZiKfG2cMX7f@j6/NF3lWiFb7wV3gk3ne1u/VXLfC2fxd6RimDBpM/wsSxhY6e3wSECikPgzXJ7UqEqeZpoJ6RFh7WtTn0pdQcmdI0dWvIst4vHrVJf6UNy3fw)

Not Unicode-safe, if it was it would be even longer.

Answer (score 0):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), 38 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(,/|x,a)(,/a:0 1_'10 11#'.Q`a`n)?x}@'
```

**Explanation:**

Lookup each character in the list `"abcdefghij1234567890"` and then index into the list `"1234567890abcdefghijX"` where `X` is the original character.

Need to find a shorter way to build the strings...

```
{(,/|x,a)(,/a:0 1_'10 11#'.Q`a`n)?x}@'
{                                  }@' / apply (@) lambda {} to each (')
                                 ?x    / lookup x in
         (                      )      / do this together
                          .Q`a`n       / index into .Q with a (gives a-z) and n (gives 0-9)
                   10 11#'             / take 10 from first list and 11 from second list
              0 1_'                    / drop 0 from first list and 1 from second list
            a:                         / save as a
          ,/                           / flatten
 (      )                              / do this together
     x,a                               / prepend x to a
    |                                  / reverse it
  ,/                                   / flatten
```

**Bonus:**

Another solution for **38 bytes**:

```
{(a,b,x)?[(b:1_11#.Q.n),a:10#.Q.a]x}@'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 135 bytes

Takes input from the console and outputs to the console.

```vb
Input""s$
For i=1To Len(s$)
c$=Mid$(s$,i,1)
n=asc(c$)-96
If-38>n Then?chr$(143+n+11^(n=-48));ElsIf n<11Then?n*(10>n),"";Else?c$;Fi
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcq9DoIwFEDhvU/RNB1ahcQrqBAEJ0lI1InZBGuRGr0gRUVfHn@2k3znVRwKa9QwZNjcO8YsJ2ndUhNDXtONRmG5JIrHW3Pk33aMA5JgXFglFJduOCdZ6XpBgjSvNK5U1XIBvjfGMcBeYOz6gZTR@mKzkuIS4H/hSMAkQekw9iO9UjxKDdnpvhuG4qCOujxV5ny5Yt3cWtvdH8/@9Yap58/miyCcfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
V=1oA q +0+"jihgfedcba"Um@W=VaX)¦É?Vw gW:X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P8zWMN9RoVBB20BbKSszIz0tNSU5KVEpNNch3DYsMULz0LLDnfZh5Qrp4VYR//8rlWRkFmcWJxaXFGXmpRsaGpkYAIESAA)

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 44 bytes

```
y/1234567890abcdefghij/abcdefghij1234567890/
```

A bit boring, I admit.

Testing:

```
$ echo 'thisisastring1124' | sed 'y/1234567890abcdefghij/abcdefghij1234567890/'
t89s9s1str9n7aabd
```